# Adding Texture to my osm city wall

Tags: texturing

( solved :D)
I have imported a city from osm.
Do it like :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NW_djQS_N8U

Now I tried to add a texture to my city walls.
But it doesnt work.
Someone has any Idea?
I add the picture to Base Color.
Then I dont know...

Here is the link to  the blender file:
including the walls

its no big thing I want to do ..
just put the texture onto the wall.

Here is the texture :D
[image]
[image]

I think I got it...
I selected UVMap when unwrapping:
[image]

Comment: Hi jento, thx for sharing the blend file which - in my opinion - is nearly always a good idea. unfortunately you didn't do file -> pack resources before uploading so we cannot see your textures.

Comment: oh I didnt knew it :)

Comment: this has to do with uv unwrapping. Your model is pretty complicated (not just a plane) and so you have to uv unwrap it. I would suggest watching a beginner uv unwrap video on yt. Basically you go to the uv editing tab, select in edit mode a face, then uv -> unwrap, then you will see the picture on your face -> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj2U3.gif also make sure you selected "UV Map" in object data properties instead of "size", when u do unwrapping [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxXaP.png

Comment: I will check your tips :D

Comment: yes it was this!

Comment: so what unwrap mode have you chosen?

Comment: I had to select UV Map . I did it just 3 times  and I think I chose cubic unwrap. But I will do it again later and check if there is a difference xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the first UV map in the *Object Data* panel:

[image]

Select the mesh in *Edit* mode and unwrap with the *Cube Projection* mode:

[image]

Create this node setup, plug an *Input > Value* into the Scale input of the *Mapping* and increase the value (or you can scale the UVs in the *UV Editor*):

[image]

Boom you get a hyper-realistic city:

[image]

In the *UV Editor*, you can still move some UVs in order to make them better match the image:

[image]

Comment: thank you. my city looks nicer now :D